# Combine two columns sharing the same values with a third column

Tags: r, dataframe, structure

I'm trying structure my sentiment list in a way I can make use of it.

I have a data frame, which is structured as this one:

```
df <- data.frame("vehicle" = c("car", "plane", "bicycle", "helicopter", "train"),
                 "Value" = c(0.5, 0.2, 0.1, -1, -0.7),
                 "type" = c("toyota, mercedes, whatever", "Airbus, Boeing", 
                            "Mountain bike", "NA", "TGV, ICE"))
```

I want the Values of "type" to be added with their values to the "vehicle" column as to get a data frame like this:

```
dfdesired <- data.frame("vehicle" = c("car", "toyota", "mercedes", "whatever", "plane", "Airbus", 
                                      "Boeing", "bicycle", "Mountain bike", "helicopter", "train", "TGV", "ICE"),
                        "Value" =c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, -1, -0.7, -0.7, -0.7))
```

Has anyone encountered a similar problem so far?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Wouldn't a structure with a new variable containing the `type` information be more useful? Like one row for each `type` which all have the same `vehicle` and `Value` information?

Comment: sadly not since in my case the "type" represents different words and "vehicle" the stemmed form of these words, which is exactly why i cant work with that frame. So i do not want type to exist anylonger as a column.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using tidyr you can do this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df  %>% mutate (type2 = strsplit(paste0(vehicle,", ",type),", ")) %>%
  unnest(type2) %>%
  select(vehicle = type2, Value)

         vehicle Value
1            car   0.5
2         toyota   0.5
3       mercedes   0.5
4       whatever   0.5
5          plane   0.2
6         Airbus   0.2
7         Boeing   0.2
8        bicycle   0.1
9  Mountain bike   0.1
10    helicopter  -1.0
11         train  -0.7
12           TGV  -0.7
13           ICE  -0.7
```

So first we add the `vehicle` to the `type` string, then we split the string into a `list`. At this point we have a `data.frame` that contains a column of lists, we use `unnest` to get one row by list item, then select the columns we want.

Comment: This somehow worked for "only" around 90% of my variables in the original dataframe the rest is still a variable with many words separated by commas, but your solution worked, thank you a lot for that.

for the other variables i will check if threre are any problems with the data set itself

Comment: you're welcome, if you can manage to circle the issue and add a dput of your data as an edit to your post I'll take a look. That may be that you don't always have spaces next to commas or that you have some special spaces (not the regular space character).

Comment: That was exactly the case. Thanks again! Problem solved! :)